# How to make bootstrap pagination work in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

My website looks like this:

**Jobs.vue:**

```
        <div
          id="jobs"
          class="job-item"
          v-for="(item, index) in showJobs"
          :key="index"
        >
          <router-link
            tag="a"
            :to="{ name: 'Detail', params: { id: item.id } }"
          >
            <h3 class="mleft-27">{{ item.position }}</h3>
          </router-link>
          <div class="job-info flex-wrap">
              <div>                
                <b>{{ item.exprerience }}</b>
              </div>
              <div>
                <b>{{ item.salary }}</b>
              </div>
              <div>                
                <b>{{ item.headequarters }}</b>              
            </div>                   
          </div>
          <div class="info-job flex-wrap">
            <div class="list-info-job" v-html="item.content"></div>
            <router-link
              :to="{ name: 'Detail', params: { id: item.id } }"
            >
              <button class="btn-detail">See Detail</button>
            </router-link>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="job-page">
          <b-pagination
            v-model="currentPage"
            :total-rows="rows"
            :per-page="perPage"
            aria-controls="jobs"
        ></b-pagination>
```

Here is the script that I followed according to the docs from Vue-Bootstrap. And another thing is that my page uses filter and search box so I have to put 2 arrays of data, is this the problem? I have updated all the script code you can check it out and give me the solution

```
<script>
import "../assets/job.css";
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  name: "jobs",
  data() {
    return {
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 2,
      search: "",
      noData: [],
      display: {
        group_filter: "",
        btn_show_filter: "",
        btn_close_filter: "",
      },
      checks: ["All", "Developer", "Tester", "Designer", "Support"],
      jobinfos: [],
      showJobs: [],
      selected: "All",
    };
  },
  computed: {
     jobs() {
      return this.showJobs.slice((this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage, (this.currentPage * this.perPage));
    },
    rows() {
      return this.showJobs.length;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getJobs();
    var self = this;
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        self.searchJob();
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async getJobs() {
      await axios
        .get(`http://localhost:1337/jobinfos`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.jobinfos = response.data;
          this.showJobs = response.data;
        })
        .catch((e) => {});
    },

    searchJob() {
      if (this.selected == "All") {
        this.showJobs = this.jobinfos;
      }
      if (this.selected != "All") {
        this.showJobs = this.jobinfos.filter((i) => i.genres === this.selected);
      }
      if (this.search.length > 1) {
        let searchedJobs = this.showJobs.filter((job) =>
          job.position.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        );
        this.showJobs = searchedJobs;
      }
    },
    selectFilter(item) {
      this.selected = item;
      if (this.selected == "All") {
        this.showJobs = this.jobinfos;
      } else {
        this.showJobs = this.jobinfos.filter((i) => i.genres === this.selected);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

To be honest i have never done pagination work in VueJS so hope to get some help from everyone. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of the **b-pagination** component is very simple - it takes a number of records (*rows*) and the number of records that should be displayed (*perPage*) and creates a component with an appropriate number of pages. The *currentPage* variable tells you on which page you should be and which records should be displayed, but it is up to you to tell the upper component what should it render. I think that in your case the **.slice()** should work. This method returns a portion of an array, based on provided values that can be determined with the use of the *currentPage* and *perPage* variables. I prepared code snipped to demonstrate that - I do not have your CSS so it might look a little bit different but it should be clearly visible how it works.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#jobs',
  data() {
    return {
      currentPage: 1,
      perPage: 2,
      showJobs: [{
          position: 'position1',
          exprerience: 'exprerience1',
          salary: 'salary1',
          headequarters: 'headequarters1'
        },
        {
          position: 'position2',
          exprerience: 'exprerience2',
          salary: 'salary2',
          headequarters: 'headequarters2'
        },
        {
          position: 'position3',
          exprerience: 'exprerience3',
          salary: 'salary3',
          headequarters: 'headequarters3'
        },
        {
          position: 'position4',
          exprerience: 'exprerience4',
          salary: 'salary',
          headequarters: 'headequarters4'
        }
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    jobs() {
      return this.showJobs.slice((this.currentPage - 1) * this.perPage, (this.currentPage * this.perPage));
    },
    rows() {
      return this.showJobs.length;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<div id="jobs">
  <div class="job-item" v-for="(item, index) in jobs" :key="index">
    <a tag="a" :to="{ name: 'Detail', params: { id: item.id } }">
      <h3 class="mleft-27">{{ item.position }}</h3>
    </a>
    <div class="job-info flex-wrap">
      <div>
        <b>{{ item.exprerience }}</b>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b>{{ item.salary }}</b>
      </div>
      <div>
        <b>{{ item.headequarters }}</b>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-job flex-wrap">
      <div class="list-info-job" v-html="item.content"></div>
      <a :to="{ name: 'Detail', params: { id: item.id } }">
        <button class="btn-detail">See Detail</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="job-page">
    <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage" aria-controls="jobs" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes but my site still shows all instead of just 2 records as i want, i added the same function jobs() as yours but it still doesn't work :( can you give me a solution can you decide? thanks u very much

Comment: And another thing is that my page uses filter and search box so I have to put 2 arrays of data, is this the problem? I have updated all the script code you can check it out and give me the solution

Comment: Can you also update your template code?

Comment: Also, did you change v-for directive in your template? From this v-for="(item, index) in showJobs" to this: v-for="(item, index) in jobs"

Comment: I can see in your script that every time you filtering/searching you are overwriting this.showJobs variable based on which the _jobs_ and _rows_ variables are determined, so it should work fine in my opinion

Comment: It gets if from computed property named __jobs__  which act like normal property but is _computed_ every time value it depends on change. You can read more about computed properties [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example)